# Linux shuts down after compiling basic children process

Tags: c, process, operating-system

In this simple C code, I am trying to create 10 children. Then do some work (such as printing the time) in them individually. Then I try to kill all of them in parent process. You will easily understand the code below. The problem is that, whenever I run this, first it gives the various outputs from children then Linux shuts down. Then I start from passing user password and everything is closed. Why this happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {
    pid_t pids[10];
    int i;
    int n= 10;

    for (i= 0; i<n; ++i) {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) <0) {
            perror("fork");
            abort();
        } 

        else if (pids[i] == 0) {
            struct timeval tv;
            time_t t;
            struct tm*info;
            char buffer[64];

            gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
            t = tv.tv_sec;
            info = localtime(&t);

            sleep(1);
            printf("CHILD PID: %d and the time is %s\n",getpid(),asctime(info));
        }
    
    }

    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    sleep(5);
    while (n >0) {
        pid = wait(&status);

        kill((long)pid, SIGTERM);
        printf("CHILD %d killed.",pid);
        --n;
    
    
    }

}
```

Comment: After `pid = wait(&status);` you *must* check the values of `pid` and `status`.

Comment: In your code some child processes execute `fork()` too recursively. And each child process executes `wait` and `kill` then.

Comment: "Linux" as in the OS shuts down? Or your process *on* Linux shuts down?

Comment: Answering "why this happens": likely `kill()` is called with `-1` which sends signal to all available processes.

Comment: @tadman OS shuts down. Not only this process.

Comment: @G.M How do I do that? Actually, I am not sure how to handle this intertwined children processes. It is easy to do some work individually but when it comes to "printing their PID one by one and kill them one by one" things got complicated for me.

Comment: `kill(whatever_wait_said_regardless_of_errors)` seems like a bad plan.

Comment: The `man` pages for [`wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and [`kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) provide information about parameters/behaviour and return values.

Comment: I still do not understand. The problem is that I need to kill particular processes by selecting myself (as selecting, I mean giving PID of each child as an input to the kill).

Comment: @ihatec Try to find where your child processes terminate. They don't terminate after `printf`! Some of them don't have it's own child processes but call `wait()`. Wait likely return `-1` as error indicator but you call `kill()` with pid -1, which means "kill all available processes".

Comment: @dimich Yes but there is not a single wait() command here. They do it automatically?

Comment: @ihatec And there is no sense to send signal to process which already terminated. You should `kill` firt and then `wait`.

Comment: @ihatec Do what? Wait for particular process? You can use `waitpid()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In process created by `fork()` all variables have the same value as before `fork`. After `fork` in this your code

```c
for (i= 0; i<n; ++i) {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) <0) {
            perror("fork");
            abort();
        }

        else if (pids[i] == 0) {
...
        }
}
```

`i` in child process is the same as it was in parent before `fork`, so `for` loop continue to execute and spawn a lot of grand children processes.

After loop is executed all spawned processes call `wait()`. Processes which are spawned on last iteration (with `i==9`) have no children, so `wait()` indicates error by returning `-1` (and `errno==ECHILD`). Then you call `kill()` with `pid==-1`, which is:

> If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1 (init)

If you want child processes to terminate by themself then you should exit explicitly, e.g. with `_exit()` function. In this case you don't need to send TERM signal:

```c
int main(void)
{
    pid_t pids[10];
    int i;
    int n = 10;

    for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            abort();
            // abort() never return, "else" is not needed
        }

        if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            struct timeval tv;
            time_t t;
            struct tm*info;

            gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
            t = tv.tv_sec;
            info = localtime(&t);

            sleep(1);
            printf("CHILD PID: %d and the time is %s\n",getpid(),asctime(info));

            _exit(0); // terminate process explicitly
        }
    }

    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    sleep(5);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        pid = wait(&status);
        // No kill needed for already exited process
        // kill((long)pid, SIGTERM);

        if (pid == -1)
        {
            perror("wait");
            abort();
        } else {
            printf("CHILD %d killed.\n", pid);
        }
        --n;
    }
}
```

If you want to terminate child processes from parent process then children should wait until terminated, but you should send signal *before* waiting for child process termination:

```c
int main(void)
{
    pid_t pids[10];
    int i;
    int n = 10;

    for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            abort();
            // abort() never return, "else" is not needed
        }

        if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            struct timeval tv;
            time_t t;
            struct tm*info;

            gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
            t = tv.tv_sec;
            info = localtime(&t);

            sleep(1);
            printf("CHILD PID: %d and the time is %s\n",getpid(),asctime(info));

            // wait until terminated
            for (;;)
                pause();
        }
    }

    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    sleep(5);

    for (i = 0; i<n; ++i) {
        if (kill(pids[i], SIGTERM) == -1) {
            perror("kill");
        }
    }

    while (n--)
    {
        pid = wait(&status);
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            perror("wait");
            abort();
        } else {
            printf("CHILD %d killed.\n", pid);
        }
    }
}
```